# No images on Nuxt static site after running npm run generate

Tags: image, vue.js, deployment, nuxt.js

I am working on a small nuxt website for a client, i havnt been using nuxt for very long but so far what i do is add target: "static" to the config when i'm ready to build for production, then send the dist folder to backend for deployment, but now i notice that after i run npm run generate images and others assets like js files do not get added to he page.. i have tried to create a new dummy project just to test, chose static mode when setting up the project, added 1 image to the project and display it in index page using

```
<img src="~/path-to-file" />
```

the image will appear normally in dev server, will also appear if project is hosted on netlify, but will not appear in git-pages or local apache server

i am confused on why this is happening, typically adding target static fixes issues like this but not this time, please help

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways to display images through nuxt. One via the assets folder, the other via the static folder.

Any images in the `/assets` folder will be bundled with webpack. These images can be referenced using:

```
<img src="~/assets/image.png"/>
```

If you do not want images to be bundled by webpack, then save them in the `/static` folder and reference using the following format:

```
<img src="/image.png"/>
```

Currently, you are using `~/` , which is shorthand to the base directory. Once you build your site for production this will no longer work, because the structure is transformed - which is why there is a discrepancy between your environments.

Comment: I have used image urls in src attributes, but that images are also not showing.